# Finding equation of circle with the given restrictions

Tags: geometry, circles, coordinate-systems

> Tangents are drawn to circle $x^2+y^2-6x-4y-11=0$ from point $P(1,8)$ touching circle at $A$ and $B$. Let there be a circle whose radius passes through point of intersection of circles $x^2+y^2-2x-6y+6=0$ and $x^2+y^2+2x-6y+6=0$ and intersect the circumcircle of $PAB$ orthogonally. Find minimum radius of such a circle.

**My attempt**
Circumcircle would be $(x-1)(x-3)+(y-2)(y-8)=0$ and centre would lie on radical axis of the given circles ie $x=0$ .
therefore equation of circle will be $x^2+y^2+2fx+c=0$. Applying orthogonality condition , $c=-19-10f$ .

I am unable to find minimum radius .

Please suggest any ways to minimise the radius or any better solution if possible .

Comment: According to relations *you* derived, $r^2 = f^2 - c = f^2+10f+19$, meaning that minimum $r$ will be *zero*!

Comment: @samjoe what should be circumcircle according to you ?

Comment: Sorry I checked again. Its correct.

Comment: What do you mean by "whose radius **passes through** point of intersection of circles" ? Let I and J be these points. Do you mean that there are two choices of circles : one with center I and passing by J, the other with center J passing by I. Or do you mean that we are only interested by **length** IJ and that the center of the circle can be elsewhere ?

Comment: The meaning of "a circle whose radius passes through point of intersection of ..." is not clear at all. Do they mean the line to which the radius belongs? Or what?

Comment: Yeah the line through which the radius passes. On that case , however the minimum radius is coming out to be zero ie point circle

Answer (score 0):

So here's how I tried to solve it :

Since the circle is passing through the point of intersection of the two circles.We can write the family of circles passing through them by S1 + $\omega $ S2, where $\omega $ is a parameter which produces the infinite circle passing through the point of intersection of the two circles.

$\ x^2+y^2-2x+6y+6 $ + $\omega $( x^2+y^2+2x-6y+6 ) = 0

Simplifying we get :

$\ x^2(1+\omega) $+ $y^2$(1+$\omega $) +x(2$\omega $ - 2) +y(-6$\omega $ - 6) + 6 + 6$\omega = 0 $

Since this is a circle it has its centre at $\ (1-\omega),(3\omega + 3) $

Now it is given in the question that a circle from this family is orthogonal to the given circle:

Note: Here I mention first circle as the one you wrote in the diameter form.

$\ r_1^2 + r_2^2 = d^2 $ where $\ r_1 $ is the radius of the first circle and $\ r_2 $ is the radius of the second circle, d is the distance between the two centres of the circles.

First circle has centre (2,5) and radius $\sqrt 10 $

Putting in the values in the formula we get :

$\ 10 $ + (1 - $\omega $)^2 + (3 $\omega $ + 3 - 5)^2 - 6 - 6$\omega $ = (1- $\omega $ - 2)^2  + (3 $\omega $ + 3 - 5) ^2:

Simplifying it all we get $\omega $ = -1/4.

Which gives us the circle when we put the value of $\omega $ in the family of circle to get the required circle.

We get the radius (root of 77 )/4